# What are the disadvantages of using the Perl debugger vs a real REPL like Devel::REPL?

Tags: perl, debugging

I usually use `perl -de 42` for obtaining an interactive Perl shell. I have seen  [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/Devel-REPL/) and I have seen some blogs like  http://www.xenoterracide.com/2010/07/making-repl-usable.html explaining how you can enhance `Devel::REPL` with the plugins, but I have not used yet.

Is it too bad to use the debugger as an interactive shell? Why?

Note:
the disadvantages mentioned in this [PerlMonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=816352) were limitations of the user, not of the Perl debugger.

Where can I read more about Perl REPL?

Is Devel::REPL ready for the limelight?

**UPDATE:**
I accepted the Pedro's answer because it answered the question that I asked, but still I would like to know when and why (if any) the use of the Perl debugger as an interactive shell is a bad idea compared with one of the Perl REPL implementations. And which Perl REPL do you prefer?

Comment: Besides pdl2 (the PDL interactive shell that uses Devel::REPL under the hood)I have seen another REPL for perl: [Carp::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp::REPL)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One disadvantage of `perl -d` is that lexical variables immediately go out of scope. Example:

```
DB<1> my $p = 123;

DB<2> print $p;

DB<3>
```

From [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#The-Perl-Debugger):

> Note that the said eval is bound by an
>   implicit scope. As a result any newly
>   introduced lexical variable or any
>   modified capture buffer content is
>   lost after the eval. The debugger is a
>   nice environment to learn Perl, but if
>   you interactively experiment using
>   material which should be in the same
>   scope, stuff it in one linescope, stuff it in one line.

Comment: Well, I'd have to say that, in response to the question "what are the disadvantages of using the perl debugger vs a real REPL like Devel::REPL?", lexical variables not working is one answer. And actually, it causes lots of problems, not just with 5.10 features. The main one is, *it's not a real REPL*; you can't do interactive development on it.

Comment: well I am using it always without strict and with global variables. I am not doing big things, only testing APIs object returns or manipulating files and it is easier draft the oneliners in a REPL than by trial and error in the shell. 

Having said that, my problem with the scope is not the variables but the perl 5:10 features that are not available because the scope issue see [How to use perl 5.10 features inside the debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539710/how-to-use-perl-5-10-features-inside-the-debugger)

Comment: from the point of view of _real REPL_ and how I formulated the question you are totally right about the variable scope. But this was a limitation that I already knew and does not affect my normal interactive usage so *in my case* this is not an issue to change to a real REPL, but not being able to use the perl5:10 features *IS*. I was more interested in knowing if there was limitations in memory usage, eficiency etc. I have not accepted your answer yet ;-) (despite it is correct), because I wanted to attract other answers that could focus in other differences more important to me.

Comment: Scoping issues? 'our' works for me!? perl -de0 DB<1> our $v=42 DB<2> p $v

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use the debugger and miss out on features, I tend to use just

```
perl -wnE'say eval()//$@'
```

I've used Devel::REPL and like it, but just never got used to using it.

An advantage to using the debugger is being able to have `$DB::single=1` to stop and single-step at a given point.

Comment: Thanks ysth, I didn't know this trick, +1 because is nice way of starting a calculator ;-) but as an interactive shell is not very usable: no history, no readline, no 'm' option to see which methods you can call in an object, you need to use Data::Dumper instead x 1, x 2 etc, no tab expansion to see the variables used.....

Comment: @Pablo: [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) works wonders for history and readline support.

Comment: There's also [`libtecla`](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~mcs/tecla/) (a `libreadline` alternative) which includes `enhance`, a tool that is similar to `rlwrap`. This combo mostly does enough for me where I can't use `Devel::REPL`. Run it thus: `enhance perl -wnE'say eval()//$@`

Answer (score 1):

Both have different goals.   The debugger is optimised for *debugging* an already written Perl script/program.  Whereas a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) primary objective is to provide quick language feedback and is optimised for (the developers) interactive input.

For eg. If I do the following in the Perl debugger:

```
DB<1> for my $x (1..10) {
```

I get a `Missing right curly or square bracket at (eval 5)...` error.

Whereas with [`Devel::REPL`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-REPL/) it allows multiple line input:

```
$ for my $x (1..3) {
> say $x;
> }
1
2
3
```

I thoroughly recommend [`Devel::REPL`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-REPL/) and with the extra plugins it becomes a handy development tool to have running beside your editor.

/I3az/

Comment: I think that with the right plugins Devel::REPL would be a nice tool. Is nicer to hit only <enter> than ' \<enter>' at the end of running lines in the debugger.

Comment: I found that pdl2 (the interactive shell for PDL) is using now Devel::REPL and load a lot of plugins:
 $  pdl2
Perldl2 Shell v0.004
Loaded plugins:
  Commands
  Completion
  CompletionDriver::Keywords
  CompletionDriver::LexEnv
  CompletionDriver::Methods
  DDS
  FindVariable
  History
  Interrupt
  LexEnv
  MultiLine::PPI
  NiceSlice
  PDLCommands
  Packages
  PrintControl
  ReadLineHistory
. NICE!!

Comment: Yes `pdl2` uses `Devel::REPL` if its installed otherwise it fallsback to `perdl` (PDL's original REPL).  `PDL` and `Devel::REPL` are indeed a nice marriage!!